# flink 1.8.3 getting a ClassNotFoundException for org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(Object) when using kakfa-connector

Tags: apache-flink

In using Flink 1.8.3 I have recently started getting a runtime 
ClassNotFoundException as shown in the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(Ljava/lang/Object;Z)V
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducerBase.<init>(FlinkKafkaProducerBase.java:146)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer09.<init>(FlinkKafkaProducer09.java:190)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer010.<init>(FlinkKafkaProducer010.java:197)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer010.<init>(FlinkKafkaProducer010.java:75)
```

I don't see any obvious old class imports when looking through the dependency graph using the gradle project-report plugin. In my gradle dependencies I am careful in depending on flink:1.8.3 jars throughout.

Additionally I don't see a version of ClosureCleaner that includes a single arg clean(Object) method. I am pretty confused by this CNFException. Unsure as to which KafkaProducer jar is in the environment when running under Flink JobManager.

It looks to me as though an old flink-java is being imported assuming the ClosureCleaner.clean(Object) single-argument invocation is old. I could use some help on this one.

thx in advance,

- james

Comment: It is `ClosureCleaner.clean(Object, boolean)`. Boolean is represented by `Z`. 
Look for `flink-java:1.8.3` dependencies in your dependency graph.

Comment: Alternatively, you can call: 
`org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(new Object(), false)` in your code to see if the class is loaded properly.

Comment: I think It could also happen when you compile with higher version of java (11) and use it in lower version of java (say 8).

Comment: perfect @chuckskull ... thx for clarifying the ClosureCleaner.clean(Object, boolean) reference. that makes way more sense.

great point on compiling *with* jdk 1.8 vs simply targeting 1.8.

Comment: I am sorry. I wasn't clear enough with jdk version part. I meant to say was that. If you are compiling flink and targetting at 11 and using the libs in the code which is ran in 1.8

Comment: @chuckskull thx again for your sound advice. in addition to the above, i deployed a flink:1.8.3 jobmanager (via helm) to which our application worked as expected. prior we were running with flink 1.9 (and 1.10 even earlier) but have had to fall back given aws:kinesis-analytics supports only 1.8. flink 1.9 ran, for us, in a flink 1.10 jobmanager deployment. I'd like to better understand the operational compatibilities across flink versions. as such, is this the best source: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html

thx again!

Comment: I think the root cause of your problem is that you are building your Job with Flink 1.8.3 and running it in 1.9+ Flink version. 
`ClosureCleaner.clean(Object, boolean)` was changed to `Object, ClosureCleanerLevel , boolean)`

Comment: In general, Flink offers source code compability across all minor releases. That means your code can be recompiled against a higher version without issues. However, modules are not guaranteed to be compatible across versions (that would limit new features too much).